# How can I prevent HTML tags from being shown in dynamic meta description?

Tags: php, html, facebook

I'll try to keep it simple: 
I have this dynamic meta description (og for facebook):

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo mb_strimwidth(nl2br($return['copete']), 0, 160, '...'); ?>">
```

But when I share it on facebook the html tags are being shown. 
Example (this is how the description is being shown in Facebook and i had to paste it as coed so you could see the html tags)

```
<h3 style="color:#aaa;font-style:italic;">Las clavitas jugaban la segunda fecha del torneo en el estadio Godoy Cruz en condición de visitante, a la es...
```

The description is fine, it's just the html tags i want to remove.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about using strip_tags()? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: That should work! :) Thanks!

Comment: Hey! This absolutely worked, thanks a lot Qirel!!

Answer (score 1):

Just use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), it will remove all html codes from your string and all will be fine.